# remote shell, change output of script to csv

Tags: shell, csv

I currently have a shell script with a section of code running remote shell commands like so:

```
grep -v "^[     ]*#" ${CONFIG_FILE} |
while read SERVER USER LOGDIR
do
{
echo "Stats for" $date
echo "${USER}"
echo "iTunes:"
time /bob/shared/ted/remote/rssh ${SERVER} "gzgrep -c \"iTunes Music\" ${LOGDIR}/*${date}*.gz | awk '-F:' '{total+=\$NF}END{print \"Total=\" total}'" 2>&1
echo
echo "Default"
time /bob/shared/ted/remote/rssh ${SERVER} "gzgrep -c \"Default Player\" ${LOGDIR}/*${date}*.gz | awk '-F:' '{total+=\$NF}END{print \"Total=\" total}'" 2>&1
echo
echo "The Rest"
time /bob/shared/ted/remote/rssh ${SERVER} "gzgrep -c \"Junk\"     ${LOGDIR}/*${date}*.gz | awk '-F:' '{total+=\$NF}END{print \"Total=\" total}'" 2>&1
} </dev/null 2>&1

done 2>${ERROR_FILE} >${STATS_FILE}
```

which gives me output like so:

```
Stats for 20120628
Rich
iTunes:
Total=0

real 0m2.09s
user 0m0.22s
sys  0m0.03s

Default:
Total=0

real 0m2.03s
user 0m0.23s
sys 0m0.00s

The Rest:
Total=0

real 0m2.03s
user 0m0.23s
sys 0m0.00s

Stats for 20120628
Ian
iTunes:
Total=2

real 0m21.44s
user 0m0.22s
sys 0m0.00s

Default:
Total=2

real 0m21.48s
user 0m0.21s
sys 0m0.02s

The Rest:
Total=0

real 0m2.03s
user 0m0.23s
sys 0m0.00s
```

etc etc...

What I want though is output like this in CSV format:

```
Rich,0,0,0
Ian,2,2,0
```

What's the simplest way to modify the above code to get the output format I require?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -v "^[     ]*#" ${CONFIG_FILE} |
while read SERVER USER LOGDIR
do
{
echo "${USER},"
time /bob/shared/ted/remote/rssh ${SERVER} "gzgrep -c \"iTunes Music\" ${LOGDIR}/*${date}*.gz | awk '-F:' '{total+=\$NF}END{print total \",\"}'" 2>&1
time /bob/shared/ted/remote/rssh ${SERVER} "gzgrep -c \"Default Player\" ${LOGDIR}/*${date}*.gz | awk '-F:' '{total+=\$NF}END{print total \",\"}'" 2>&1
time /bob/shared/ted/remote/rssh ${SERVER} "gzgrep -c \"Junk\"     ${LOGDIR}/*${date}*.gz | awk '-F:' '{total+=\$NF}END{print total}'" 2>&1
} </dev/null 2>&1 | tr -d '\n'

done 2>${ERROR_FILE} >${STATS_FILE}
```

I removed the extra echo's, appended commas and made sure it's on one line. Try it.

If you don't want the timing info either, just delete all the `time` invocations.

Comment: Couldn't you do just one rssh per server, putting the functionality that's currently being done by `grep` into the `awk` script?

Comment: Definitely, but he asked for the smallest modification possible, so I didn't try to make the whole sensible.

Comment: Good point Charles! Can't see the wood for the trees somtimes hehe ;) cheers!